# Plivo outbound call getting 3 times if rejected

Tags: android, plivo

I am using Plivo with android for outbound call and working fine but getting some issues.If A call to B, and call rejected by B again and again then total 3 times call get from A. how can i stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

Which country are you calling to? This could be carrier related issue. Can you please raise a [support ticket](https://support.plivo.com/) with us providing the Call UUID? We can help you resolve this faster.